# how can I enable the user to add fragments dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I am trying to create an app to work on both tablet and legacy phones that adds fragments dynamically based on user interaction. An example of an app that mimics this logic is called pulse

When the user selects a news source, it is dynamically added to the bottom. I am wondering how this is done. Do I have to create new activity every time a new fragment is added?

Anyone, please advise. An example would be duly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to create activity. You can add, remove, hide and show fragments in current activity.

Please read [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) documentation and take a look at [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html).

Comment: Thanks Inazaruk. I have looked at the Fragment documentation but since I am newbie, I'd prefer a working example to refer to. Any ideas?

Comment: The link I gave you has many examples. You can also take a look at API Demos app or at support library demo (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/index.html)

Comment: Thanks Inazaruk, let me have a look!!

Answer (score 0):

Refer [GoogleIO](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#hg%2Fandroid),[CheckoutLink](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout) this explains how add fragment dynamically

Comment: Thanks Santosh. Could you re-edit your answer and provide me the direct link to the article? thanks